# Python-Twitter: Can't covert 'bytes' object to string

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-twitter

I am trying to encode tweets from unicode to utf-8 but I get the following error gets logged on CLI when I execute the file:

```
File "PI.py", line 21, in analyze
text += s.text.encode('utf-8')
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Here is my code:

```
text = "" 
for s in statuses:
    if (s.lang =='en'):
        text += s.text.encode('utf-8')
```

And here are the packages I am importing:

```
import sys
import operator
import requests
import json
import twitter
from watson_developer_cloud import PersonalityInsightsV2 as PersonalityInsights
```

How can I get the strings (tweet text) to be converted to the right encosing properly so I can use them? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your `text` as bytes by appending a leading `b`:

```
text = b""
```

This will allow the new bytes object to be concatenated without errors to the existing bytes object `text`